# How can my app playback videos like metro tube does for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, youtube, video-player

I have to code an Windows Phone  7 application which playback videos from YouTube. That's kind of normal, but the first approach it's to playback them in the same way as MetroTube does it (see http://www.metrotubeapp.com/ ) (for example you can playback the youtube video without going to fullscreen and also have playback controls)

[image: enter image description here][1]

I do not have any idea of how to achieve this so, perhaps an embedded page based on [You tube video integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017067/you-tube-video-integration) but not quite sure yet.

Any idea of how to create this very flexible YouTube player for WP7?